# Litepicker - can't put dates into the input field with the multiselect plugin

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I try to use the Litepicker datimepicker component with the multiselect plugin, but it does not put selected dates in the input field.
Could you help me to resolve the issue?

Here is the example on codepen for reproducing the issue.
https://codepen.io/Pavlo-Kravchuk/pen/yLQjVbg

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/litepicker/dist/bundle.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker" class="form-control" style="width: 250px" readonly="">

<script>
const picker = new Litepicker({
  element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
  plugins: ['multiselect']
})
</script>
```